# Google Sheets: How to grab unique names and numbers from one sheet and adding it to another sheet based on a specific value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just started working at a new company and I thought that I'd make a spreadsheet for my personal use. My boss came across me working on that spreadsheet and loved it so far. They've been manually entering values into their own spreadsheets since they've started and I thought it was super tedious, so I've been working on my own for the last week trying to improve efficiency on my end. Now my bosses want me to do this for the other branches... so the pressure is real for me. I've completed every other feature they've requested, but I'm struggling with this last one so I'm here now requesting help.

I have two sheets. One called "Inspection Results" and "Still Hasn't Passed Inspection."

"Inspection Results" looks something like this:

| Timestamp | Date | Name | MS Number | Address | Jurisdiction | Inspection Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/21/2021 | 4/21/2021 | John Smith | MS12345 | 123 Test St | Orange | Passed |
| 4/20/2021 | 4/20/2021 | John Smith | MS12345 | 123 Test St | Orange | Failed |
| 4/21/2021 | 4/21/2021 | Rick Grimes | MS12356 | 123 Meme St | Riverside | Passed |
| 4/19/2021 | 4/19/2021 | Michelle Obama | MS54321 | 123 Demo St | Long Beach | Failed |
| 4/18/2021 | 4/18/2021 | Michelle Obama | MS54321 | 123 Demo St | Long Beach | Failed |
| 4/18/2021 | 4/18/2021 | Courage Dog | MS98765 | 123 Coward St | Orange | Cancelled |

"Still Hasn't Passed Inspection" currently looks like this:

| Name | MS Number |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
|  |  |

I want to search every row in "Inspection Results" and find the Names(Column C) of the people that do not have a inspection result(Column G) of "Passed" and write a new row in "Still Hasn't Passed Inspection" with the Name(Column C) and MS Number(Column D) of those people that could not be found with a "Passed" inspection result.

I want the table in "Still Hasn't Passed Inspection" to have unique rows. For example, there are some rows in "Inspection Results" that I have the same Name and Inspection Result. In the table that I posted, Michelle Obama failed inspection. I only want Michelle Obama to appear one time in the "Still Hasn't Passed Inspection" sheet. John Smith failed inspection one day, but passed on the following day so he wouldn't be included in the table.

Basically, based on the example table I posted above, I want "Still Hasn't Passed Inspection" to look like this:

| Name | MS Number |
| --- | --- |
| Michelle Obama | MS54321 |
| Courage Dog | MS98765 |

I'm trying to automate this process so I, or whoever, doesn't have to keep manually entering and deleting rows every time someone finally passes inspection. If someone submits a "Passed" entry into "Inspection Results" for someone that previously "Failed" or "Cancelled", I want "Still Hasn't Passed Inspection" to be updated.

Is there a way I can accomplish this with certain formulas or am I going to have to create a script on this and, if so, does anyone have a reference they can point me towards? I'm not an experienced coder. I'm not familiar with Javascript and its syntax, but I do know how variables, if statements, and for loops work. I'm not asking anyone to write me a bunch of code on this. This isn't your responsibility. If you want to, of course, it would always be appreciated. Any hints or reference towards resolving this would be amazing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a big fan of the [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) (`QUERY(data, query, [headers])`) function. Using it, you could do something like this on "Still Hasn't Passed Inspection"

```
=query(Inspection Results!A2:G, "Select C, D where G = 'Failed' OR G = 'Cancelled'")
```

This is saying to look at the data in the `Inspection Results` sheet, column `A2` through `G` (specifying no row number will go to the end of the sheet).

It is then grabbing the contents of column `C` and column `D` in `Inspection Results` and pulling those into the sheet with the `query` function, in separate columns, a row for each result. It will only pull in the results where column `G` (Inspection Results in your example) is the string "Failed".

You would then need a query to get the ones that have passed, and filter the resultset based on that, such as:

```
=filter(query(A2:G, "Select C, D where G = 'Failed' OR G = 'Cancelled'"), arrayformula(not(countif(query(A2:G, "Select D where G = 'Passed'"), query(A2:G, "Select D where G = 'Failed' OR G = 'Cancelled'")))))
```

This is essentially saying, "Filter my query of not-passed inspections by looking at passed inspections, and not including any with the same MS Number"

Comment: Can I add a second condition to that function? For example, I want to also include the cancelled inspections too.

Comment: Modified the example to include "Cancelled".

Comment: Thank you Doug. The main problem that I am facing now is when I add second entry for the same person with a "Passed" inspection result, the old failed result is still in the "Still Hasn't Passed Inspection" sheet. Any advice on how to fix that?

Comment: This may be a little convoluted, but you can use 3 queries to do it.. Will update the answer, since this was in your original question and I missed it.

Comment: OK, updated. Does that meet the requirements? Is there any situation where one passes, but later fails, and that needs to be accounted for?

Comment: Once again, Thank you Doug. This means a lot. I've been pulling hairs because of this whole feature. There is no situation like that. Once the job passes, it's done. I tried putting that formula into the cell, but I'm getting parse error. #ERROR!

Comment: Correction: It works if it's on the same sheet. I just have to edit a few things so it works on the new sheet. That, or I can just keep them on the same sheet.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I pulled it from a sheet I threw together where everything was on the same sheet